# Multiprocessing uses python 2.7 even if I am in a python 3 env

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I am trying to run a code (confronting pairwise strings in a dict basically) using concurrent.futures.
The code looks as follows (where masterprova is a dict of 100 elements):

```
import concurrent.futures
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations
#import fuzz

def process_chunk(masterprova_chunk, d, threshold):
    for (i,ii),(j,jj) in combinations(masterprova_chunk, 2):
        if jj not in d[i] and fuzz.partial_ratio(ii,jj) >= threshold:
            d[i].add(jj)
    return d

threshold = 90
d = defaultdict(set)

for (i,ii) in master.items():
    d[i].add(ii)
    
# Split masterprova into chunks for parallel processing
num_workers = 4 # number of parallel processes to use
chunk_size = len(masterprova)//num_workers
masterprova_chunks = [list(masterprova.items())[i:i + chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(masterprova), chunk_size)]
```

everything is good until here...then when I try putting the chunks together calling concurrent.futures as follows:

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_workers) as executor:
    results = [executor.submit(process_chunk, masterprova_chunk, d, threshold) for masterprova_chunk in masterprova_chunks]
    for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
        d.update(f.result())
```

an error occurs referring to multiprocessing in python 2.7. The fact is that I am using python 3. and I have already tried to uninstall multiprocessing and re-install it with pip3 directly in the notebook but it did not work. The error looks as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/single_auth_paper/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:3397 in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  Input In [53] in <cell line: 1>
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_workers) as executor:

  File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/single_auth_paper/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/__init__.py:44 in __getattr__
    from .process import ProcessPoolExecutor as pe

  File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/single_auth_paper/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/process.py:51 in <module>
    import multiprocessing as mp

  File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/__init__.py:64 in <module>
    from multiprocessing.process import Process, current_process, active_children

  File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py:271
    except SystemExit, e:
           ^
SyntaxError: multiple exception types must be parenthesized
```

How can I fix it? How can multiprocessing be used with python 3. rather than python 2.7 in a jupyter notebook that uses python 3. specifically?

Thanks

Comment: I'm almost certain that you have a botched conda or python2 install because you should never need to manually install multiprocessing as it's part of the standard library. Personally, I would check my .bashrc and similar to see whether anything is messing with PATH or PYTHONPATH because something is going awry. 

A hackier approach would be to try different pips to install multiprocessing e.g. `pip3 install multiprocessing` or `python -m pip install multiprocessing` but, again, there is an underlying problem that it is probably better to diagnose than try to work around.

Comment: I see. Do you think tha changing my pythonpath with sys can improve on that?

Comment: Do you fiddle with the python library or import paths?

Comment: Oh I saw he problem. The problem is that I am using fuzzyfuzzy which apparently is stored in python2.7 folder. Hence I change the sys.path back in time!

Comment: Occam's razor ;)